# Why init method of GetBuilder not returning the desired controller with Get.find in getx flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to make different instances of same controller each with it's unique name or tag but I am experiencing odd behavior with the init field`init:Get.find<CountController>(tag: "myController"),`

- first: I tried using the following line to specify which controller I want to be passed in the builder method i.e. `controller`
  But the print statements I used after shows that the controller in the builder is something else with tag name that is `'null'` (as specified in the default value of the tag in `controller.dart`) :

```
 I/flutter ( 4290): with Get.find has tag:  myController
 I/flutter ( 4290): controller from builder has tag: null
```

- secondly just uncommenting the `//tag: "myController",` and commenting init line  showed the desired output:

```
I/flutter ( 4290): with Get.find has tag:  myController
I/flutter ( 4290): controller from builder has tag: myController
```

- now my Question is why init didn't work in the first approach, to my understanding it requires an instance of the controller, but it doesn't seem to do anything with it. like it just asserts that is there and that's it??!

controller.dart ( class has both reactive variable and update function because I was experimenting with both Getx and GetBuilder ) :

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class CountController extends GetxController {
  String? tag = "null";
  RxInt count = RxInt(1);

  CountController({this.tag, int? value}) {
    if(value != null) count = RxInt(value);
  }

  void increment(){
      if(count.value == 24) {
        Get.closeAllSnackbars();
        Get.snackbar("Item Count", "You can't increase count more!");
        return;
      }
      count.value++;
      update();
  }

  void decrement(){
    if(count.value == 1)  return;
    count.value--;
    update();
  }
}
```

Test.dart: (I am just using Get.put in the constructor here for simplicity)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_app/controllers/count_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key){
    Get.put(CountController(tag: "myController"), tag: "myController");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<CountController>(
      init: Get.find<CountController>(tag: "myController"),
      //tag: "myController",
      builder: (controller){
        print("with Get.find has tag:  ${Get.find<CountController>(tag: "myController").tag}");
        print("controller from builder has tag: ${controller.tag}");
        return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Hello Flutter")));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @RandalSchwartz 
May I ask for the link for this flutter server ?

Comment: See http://flutter.dev/community for all the official and blessed community channels.